# Multi merchant payment system with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment

I need to build web application where users can sell goods. 
Each user should be able to get money directly on his PayPal account.
Can you suggest which PayPal service/payment method (or other payment system) it is better/safely to use in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Important question: do you need to be able to collect a fraction of this money (as a middleman), or is it okay for the payment to go directly from customer to merchant without modification?

Comment: No, this should be direct payments between users.

Comment: Hi Artemm, Have you implemented the multiple merchant with a transaction?

Comment: Hello Amber, Yes, I would like to collect a commission. Can we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily set up (if I read your requirements correctly). You would have to create your part of the system, but that's obvious.

The rest, specifically vendor payments, could be handled all by PayPal.

PayPal could process the orders into individual accounts. You would simply have to use the same IPN notification file for each Buy Link. This IPN notification file is what PayPal uses to notify an order has come. It does not matter that it may have come TO Suzie's or TO Bob's account.

So, your notification script gets the order -- Then, your internal system differentiates the vendor and ... that's it ;).

IPN is very simple too, and they've got nice templates in various languages to get you started.

I'm sure there are alternate ways to do it, but IPN is what I personally use, combined with a back-end system. I even have another vendor whose plug-in for my product I sell. Money goes directly into his PayPal account by simply changing the recipient email in the Buy URL (or form).

Any competent programmer should be able to handle this with ease. The proficiencies would be SQL/database experience and web coding (any language). That's about it. A non-programmer could probably even learn, though needs to be careful to sanitize the input to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Hi, I know that this thread has been dead for years but I suddenly hav ethe same issues in deciding as to how to deal with multiple merchant accounts in a site.So,if I try to do this with paypal, will it be able to just send the money to a specific person with requiring like a unique Merchant Key(diff from Merchant ID - ala google checkout)? Also,is encrypting their merch Id still essential in this type of data? Thanks!

Comment: There is no 'merchant key' afaik with PayPal, you just send money to the recipient at whatever email address. This can be done via an HTML address with parameters about the transaction (e.g. cost), a FORM, or through PayPal (obviously). If Receiving payments, you set up an IPN (Instant Payment Notification) script. This script does a call-back to the PayPal server to verify the transaction ID is correct, then fulfills or denies the order based on that.

Comment: So does that mean I can just have them provide an email and then I can make transactions? Does paypal have a sample on how to create a IPN script? Using MVC .net C# atm.

Comment: Yes, and they have samples. I use PHP, which they had a sample for. Dunno about the others, but it is trivial.

Comment: And note to confirm you *can* cause use it to send money between two different people, but have your IPN script handle the order/transaction  fulfillment (or whatever it may be). You can specify the IPN callback URL on the HTML query string, or in the FORM variables.

Comment: so hold on. i can split the money to let's say me and a merchant with only one transaction?

Comment: Not automatically you couldn't 'split' it, not without more advanced APIs used anyway... but you could have money sent to one merchant, but your server handle the transaction (the IPN notification). PayPal has an excellent sample IPN script in several languages. Find the developer area of PayPal, https://www.x.com/ (yes, it is really x.com) ... One thing that is certain is that IPN is one of the easiest ways to integrate with PayPal, though with their samples there are several avenues available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExpressCheckout, this means that your sellers do not need tho have Pro accounts, but login and payment will occur in paypal's popup window. You can also use more advanced integration, but this might require the merchants to upgrade their account, and this might cost them money in every month.

You also need to collect API keys from merchants and store them in a *very* safe location, or collect the money yourself, and pay for the merchants using paypal's API code, but this will introduce additional (transfer) costs.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to write it from scratch. I mean, from some bare framework.